# Accessing NameValuePair

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a", "yes"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("b", "Value 2"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", "Value 3"));
```

How would I access the last NameValuePair's value and input it into a String. I am currently trying:

```
 String tester = postParameters.get(3).getValue();
```

but my application crashes.

How do I get tester to become "Value 3"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList is zero indexed (ie first index is 0), so this should work better;

```
String tester = postParameters.get(2).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList index starts from 0.

```
String tester = postParameters.get(2).getValue();
```